# QGIS cluster groups of houses

Tags: qgis, clustering

I want to cluster houses into groups of 32 in a QGIS point file, with the clusters arranged to select houses which are in rows.  All my houses are in rows of 5-10 and I want to exclude houses which are not in rows from the clusters. Does anyone know of something I can use in QGIS?